# Removing quotation marks from JSON encoded string

Tags: javascript, php, json, string

I currently have a JSON encoded string generated by inputting values from a array, it is as follows -

```
"["{value: 97049}","{value: 84866}","{value: 39402}","{value: 30250}","{value: 33363}"]"
```

I need to convert it to the following format :

```
"[{value: 97049},{value: 84866},{value: 39402},{value: 30250},{value: 33363}]"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Neither of those are or contain JSON.  (property names must be quoted)

Comment: Is the first example the actual characters in the string? Do you need the result to have quote marks around it when you're done? Do you want code in javascript or php?

Comment: I suspect what he posted is what `console.log()` displayed. It simply wraps quotes around a string, it doesn't escape the embedded quotes as you would have to if it were a string literal in code.

Comment: Hi, the first example is a var_dump from a php array where I have used json_encode. sorry for making all this quite vague am self taught and confused.

Comment: Hi managed, to sort it. Thanks for all the input !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$input = $json_var;

$input = str_replace( '"', '', $input ); // strip em
$input = '"' . $input . '"'; // wrap back around
```

Answer (score 2):

JS:

```
var json_array = JSON.parse(json_string);
for (var i = 0; i < json_array.length; i++) {
    json_array[i] = JSON.parse(json_array[i];
}
```

PHP:

```
$json_array = json_decode($json_string);
$json_array = array_map('json_decode', $json_array);
```

It would probably be better to fix this at the source. If it's supposed to be an array of objects, don't quote each array element before adding them to the array.

Comment: Your answer is nice, but written in JS. Wasn't OP looking for PHP code or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Tags: `javascript`, `json`, `string`, `php` - ambigous

Comment: Do you really think that the call to `JSON.parse` is going to succeed with that input?

Comment: See the comment I posted up above.

Comment: Hi, I was looking for it in PHP. Sorry for being vauge, im relatively new to all this.

Comment: Added the PHP solution. Basically, just just use `json_decode` instead of `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myQuotedJson = '"["{value: 97049}","{value: 84866}","{value: 39402}","{value: 30250}","{value: 33363}"]"';

var myUnquotedJson = myQuotedJson.replace(/"/, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this:

```
var input = '"["{value: 97049}","{value: 84866}","{value: 39402}","{value: 30250}","{value: 33363}"]"';
 output = '"' + input.replace('"','') + '"';
 //Alerts your output
 alert(output );
```